# Properly Discontinuous Group Action on $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I'm trying to prove that the $\mathbb{Z}-$action on $\mathbb{C}^{\times}:=(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\},\times)$ defined by $z\mapsto q^kz$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that $0<|q|<1$, is properly discontinuous.

For all $z_0\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, let $U_{\epsilon}:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}^{\times}:|z-z_0|<\epsilon\}$ be an open nbhd of $z_0$. I want to find an $\epsilon$ such that
$$|q^kz_0-z_0|=|z_0||q^k-1|\geq \epsilon>0$$
for all $k\neq 0$. Does it exist? is it just $\epsilon<|q|$?

Moreover, for $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that $\mathbb{Z}.z_1\neq \mathbb{Z}.z_2$, I want to prove that there exist nbhds $U_1,U_2$ such that 
$$\{q^kz:z\in U_1\cap U_2\}=\emptyset$$
for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the iterating sequence $S = (q^k z_0)_{k \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$.  The first iterate is $z_0$, lying on the circle $\{z \in \Bbb{C} : |z| = |z_0|\}$, of radius $|z_0|$.  The next iterate is $q z_0$, lying on the circle $\{z \in \Bbb{C} : |z| = |q||z_0|\}$, of radius $|q||z_0|$.  Since $0<q<1$, this second circle is contained in the disk bounded by the first circle.  Continuing, each iterate lies on a circle contained by the disk interior to the circles containing each prior iterate.  This means that if you set $\varepsilon < |z_0| - |q||z_0|$, the difference between the radii of the first two circles, then $U_\varepsilon$ will contain no point of the second or subsequent circles, so $U_\varepsilon \cap S = \{z_0\}$, as desired.

In your "Moreover", replace the above "circles" by annuli.  The first annulus has inner radius $\inf_{z \in U_1 \cap U_2} |z|$ and outer radius $\sup_{z \in U_1 \cap U_2} |z|$.  Now construct the iterated sequence of annuli and choose the neighborhoods small enough that the annuli don't intersect.

Comment: and what if $k<0$?

Comment: @Jackristin : You drew the picture, right?  the same argument applies, with tiny modifications.  The increasing sequence of circles containing the $(q^k z)_{k < 0}$ each bound disks containing all the circles of the points with larger $k$.  The distances between the circles satisfy $|q^{n-1}x| - |q^n x| > |q^n x| - |q^{n+1} x|$, so choosing $\varepsilon$ small enough to avoid the inner circle automatically avoids the outer circle.  The annulus argument goes through with the analogous modifications.